# Saving SQL Queries in SAP

Tags: sql, abap, sap-basis

Hey guys I've written some SQL statements in SAP, I want to be able to save the code and run it when ever I need to. The SQL code either locks or unlocks specified users based on the UFLAG value entered. I'm fairly new to SAP/SQL and have no idea on how to actually save this small/simple script.

I used TCODE: db13 then navigated to the Diagnostics tab -> SQL Command Editor.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Just create your Z-program and run it whenever you need.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, sql scripts cannot be saved in the system. However, you can export to txt and import from txt file.
[image]
In my opinion, it is not a proper way to handle this at db layer. You should write a program and should use open sql statements.

Comment: I'm on 7.5 SP3 and I can save them just fine :) They must have added this recently.

Comment: Thanks Oguz, yeah i think it isn't best practice to do this on the database layer. Will most likely attempt to write it in a program. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse(ADT) you can save them as favourites in SQL console. There is a downward arrow in RUN, click on the same will give you options to 'add to favourites', manage favourites etc.